# xaxes labels not displaying correctly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a histogram based on the following dataset.

[image: dataset]

I want independent x axes with labels, so I tried the following code:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig = px.histogram( x=df["mun"], y=df["cust"], color=df["prod"], facet_col=df["pr"] )
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)
fig.show()
```

As you can see the second plot does not show the labels for x. I don't understand why this is happening. How can I fix it?

[image: graph]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening - it may be some bug in the categorical axis labels when plotly generates facet plots.

You can manually specify `category_array=['D','E']` when you update the xaxes, which is admittedly a brittle workaround:

```
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True, categoryarray=['D','E'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly I need a dynamic way to update the xaxes, I'm working with a bigger dataset and I can't manually specify all the labels :(

Comment: Thank to your workaround I found a way:
 `categoryarray=pd.unique(df["mun"])`
Thank you so much for leading me to the right answer!

Comment: @Tom I am glad my answer was helpful!